# Prove $\partial(S)=\partial(\bar S)$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> **Definition.** We call $\mathbf x$ a **boundary point** of $S$ if every $\epsilon$-disk $D(\mathbf x, \epsilon)$ contains point of $S$ and $S'$(the complement of $S$). The set of all boundary points of $S$ is called the **boundary** of $S$ (notation: $\partial(S)$ ). The **closure** of a set is the set $\bar S=S\cup \partial(S)$.
>
> Prove that $\partial(S)=\partial(\bar S)$.

I can show $\bar S$ and $\partial(S)$ are closed set.

Comment: It is easy to check that $\partial S = \overline{S} \cap \overline{S^c}$. So we always have $$\partial(\overline{S}) = \overline{\overline{S}} \cap \overline{\overline{S}^c} \subseteq \overline{S} \cap \overline{S^c} = \partial(S). $$ The strict inclusion is possible as in the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not true. Consider $S=\Bbb Q$ in the usual topology of $\Bbb R$.